How to tell compiler that it is ok to move struct field to box and then move it away from struct
Here is a small, failing to compile, piece of code:
pub struct Owns<T: SomeTrait> {
    one: T,
    two: T,
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> SomeOtherTrait for Owns<T> {
    fn method2(&self) {
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct Foo {
    items: Vec<Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct FooBuilder<T: SomeTrait> {
    last: T,
    items: Vec<Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait>>,
}

impl<T: SomeTrait> FooBuilder<T> {
    fn init(mut self, t: T) -> Self {
        self.last = t;
        self
    }

    fn add(mut self, t: T) -> Self {
        let last = std::mem::replace(&mut self.last, t);
        self.items.push(Box::new(Owns { one: last, two: t }));
        self
    }
}

FooBuilder keep some generic value in the last field up to the moment, when I call add function.
I want to transfer value from one struct field to another struct field putted to the box. And I want to tell Rust, that value T: SomeTrait does not contain some references, that will become invalid.
Rust does not trust me and keeps whining, that:
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:38:25
   |
38 |         self.items.push(Box::new(Owns { one: last, two: t }));
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                         |
   |                         the parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime...
   |                         ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
30 | impl<T: SomeTrait + 'static> FooBuilder<T> {

So, I have tried 'static and it works, but it gives me headache in other parts of the project.
So I made another attempt to negotiate with compiler:
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct FooBuilder<'a, 'b, T: SomeTrait>
where
    T: 'a,
    Self: 'b,
{
    last: T,
    items: Vec<Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait + 'a>>,
    _p: PhantomData<Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait + 'b>>,
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: SomeTrait> FooBuilder<'a, 'b, T> {
    fn init(mut self, t: T) -> Self {
        self.last = t;
        self
    }

    fn add(mut self, t: T) -> Self {
        let last = std::mem::replace(&mut self.last, t);
        self.items.push(Box::new(Owns { one: last, two: t }));
        self
    }

    fn build(Self { items, .. }: Self) -> Foo {
        Foo { items }
    }
}

So, now it works for add method.
But still, builder pattern must use it's value. And I have created build method, which fails to compile.
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:49:14
   |
37 | impl<'a, 'b, T: SomeTrait> FooBuilder<'a, 'b, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
49 |     fn build(Self { items, .. }: Self) -> Foo {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type annotation requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`

And this makes me to use static all around my code in dependent libraries.
So, if there exists some "spell", which tells rust that it is okay to keep not-so-static lifetime for these generics, I will be happy.

Foo::items is implicitly Vec<Box<dyn SomeOtherTrait + 'static>> it has to get a lifetime as well as the builder.

And I want to tell Rust, that value T: SomeTrait does not contain some references, that will become invalid. → that's exactly what T: SomeTrait + 'static means.

Adding + 'static and mock declarations for the missing traits makes your code compile: playground → please provide a [mre] for any remaining issue.

Possibly relevant: Should trait bounds be duplicated in struct and impl?. TLDR, your struct should be defined as plain pub struct Owns<T> { … } without the T: SomeTrait bound.

This is a choice of "verbosity on definition" vs "verbosity on usage".

? I don't understand your last comment: adding the bounds on the struct definition increases both the verbosity on definition (obviously) and the verbosity on usage (since now you need to repeat the bounds every time you use the struct).
